# Many to Many Relations in YII

Tags: yii

I'm trying to create a blog system using YII. Examples and Tutorials are available. But they use a multi-value table for a Post. Its something like

<kbd>Post(Id, Title, Content, Author, Tags)</kbd>

Here there are multiple values (separated by comas) in Tags column. So I created a schema to avoid this and now I have tables like this,

<kbd>Post(Id, Title, Content, Author)</kbd>
<kbd>Tag(Id, Name)</kbd>

<kbd>PostHaveTags(Post_Id, Tag_Id)</kbd>

after normalizing the schema.

I could manage to make a relation in relations() method. But I cannot figure out how to get inputs from a view and validate values of 'tags'. Can anyone help me regarding this please?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use javascript to allow your forms to grow dynamically and include zero, one or many tags. which you can validate in the model using [custom validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/).

Comment: Hey, I can validate and get values from the form. But I still cannot add them to the database. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you're treating them. Usually I like to pass the data in the form of an array via POST, so usually I can iterate over $_POST['RelatedRecords'], Which would include the "Serialized" information from the dynamically grown form. Someting like creating a related record for each Item in the serialized list of atributes.. All this in the controller actions.

Comment: Also, verify that the data is correctly being validated, and wether or not the "Parent Record" exists in the database (which for me, it's a MUST). This means that you have to  save the parent record first, and all the children/related records (tags) afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. And Thank you so much. After doing some self trials, I could find the answer. And I'm going to post it as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. And here is what I did,

First I got the appropriate data from the view and validated them, defining some rules. Then in the afterSave() method I inserted the gathered data into relative relations manually. I don't know whether there is an easy way. But I think, if so, YII will generate the code for us. :)

Thanx guys for helping.